# Baffling compile error: "A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: ChangeEventHeader"

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error, platform-event, change-data-capture

Why is it that this will not compile:

```
trigger AccountChangeTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert) {
    String dmlType = Trigger.new[0].ChangeEventHeader.changetype;
    ...
```

> A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: ChangeEventHeader

But this will:

```
trigger AccountChangeTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert) {
    EventBus.ChangeEventHeader header = Trigger.new[0].ChangeEventHeader;
    String dmlType = header.changetype;
    ...
```

(As will this:

```
trigger AccountChangeTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert) {
    String dmlType = Trigger.new[0].ChangeEventHeader.getChangeType();
    ...
```

)

I would have thought the compiler would treat (1) and (2) the same way, especially since Trigger.new[0] is always an instance of EventBus.ChangeEventHeader (`instanceof` check confirms this).

Relatedly, I haven't been able to locate the documentation on what type of object or base class is behind AccountChangeEvent (and other ___ChangeEvent objects).